# Filename path mapping, when using docker/container/vm

Tags: xdebug

If xdebug provides information about files (e.g. stack traces), we can configure the way it works.

https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#filename_format

But on my host machine, the files have a different location, then on my guest machine.
E.g.: /home/me/project/myapp VS /app

Is there any way to configure xdebug so that I can map the files and get the correct host file paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this with Xdebug.

I have been working on a plan to allow for something like this, but it has not concluded into an actual implementation idea. I would recommend that you file an issue at Xdebug's issue tracker at https://bugs.xdebug.org to register your interest in this feature.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, i added my wish: https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=2099